# Automatic Database Filler : ORM, Performance, ... testing purposes

Tags: database, database-design, orm, performance-testing, database-testing

I'm interested in software tool, which can fill up my database based on parameters with some random data.

Doesn't matter if it is something based on desktop application, online tool

What it should fulfill:

- Filling models based on HABTM, hasMany, belongsTo, ... relations
- Accept MAX and MIN values for number types
- Accept number of generated items in specific models
- Multi-platform (if desktop-application it means written in Java or some script language)

Why?

- Testing design (layouts filled with long texts)
- Testing performance of Application/API/Server-Side
- Testing data-type security, allocations, ...
- ...

Is there anything usable in moment? I'm not able to find anything

Comment: Programmers is also a Q&A site by definition, so if you don't think the question is suitable for Q&A, it is not suitable for Programmers either. Programming tools, on the other hand, are on-topic here. It sounds like you're asking for a specific tool to help you with a programming task, so I'm going to leave the question open here. (Although you are right - it's not a great fit for Q&A.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will fill *everything* for you, relationships and all, but it is handy for creating some basic filler data:

[GenerateData.com](http://www.generatedata.com)